# Ruby output is inconsistent

Tags: ruby

I am getting some weird output with my `Ruby` code. Here is the code:

```
            mDate = schedule['date']
            sTime = schedule['startTime']
            eTime = schedule['endTime']

            puts "Original Start Time: #{sTime}"
            puts "Original End Time: #{eTime}"
            puts "Original Date: #{mDate}"

            sDate = mDate
            eDate = mDate

            puts "sDate: #{sDate}"
            puts "eDate: #{eDate}"

            @startTime = sDate.concat("T" + sTime + "Z")
            @endTime = eDate.concat("T#{eTime}Z")
            @date = schedule['date']

            puts "Start Time: #{@startTime}"
            puts "End Time: #{@endTime}"
            puts "Date: #{@date}"

            puts "Original Start Time: #{sTime}"
            puts "Original End Time: #{eTime}"
            puts "Original Date: #{mDate}"
```

Here is the output:

```
Original Start Time: 15:00:00
Original End Time: 15:00:00
Original Date: 2012-12-05
sDate: 2012-12-05
eDate: 2012-12-05
Start Time: 2012-12-05T15:00:00ZT15:00:00Z
End Time: 2012-12-05T15:00:00ZT15:00:00Z
Date: 2012-12-05T15:00:00ZT15:00:00Z
Original Start Time: 15:00:00
Original End Time: 15:00:00
Original Date: 2012-12-05T15:00:00ZT15:00:00Z
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why 1. values are changing 2. why concat is adding the value twice 3. wtf I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sDate = mDate.clone
eDate = mDate.clone
```

otherwise they all end up being the *same object*.

Also, please explain something about the problem, instead of just dumping code and output. By the end of your question, I read "wtf I'm doing wrong here" as "wtf I'm doing here".

Comment: Or just don't use mutating methods (like `concat`) when you don't intend to mutate.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Valid. "Why are values changing?" "Because you changed them!" :D